# Replacing Apache POI Jars to latest version

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, heap-memory

Our application currently using Apache POI : 3.5 Version for Excel Reports.  We are frequently facing Java Heap Space issues due to large excel creation. One of the solution suggested is to replace the old Apache POI jars with the latest one. But changing affects the existing application with some deprecated methods.

Is there any way to handle this??? Or do we need to change all those methods manually.

Comment: Most of the Apache lib comes with examples. You can check if the newer version contains documentation regarding migration from your version to latest version.

Comment: Upgrading your jars might not necessarily fix your heap space problem. If OOXML based files (e.g. .xlsx) are an option for you AND the heap space problem occurs when generating the reports, you might consider switching to SXSSF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Obvious, You need to handle it manually.

Latest is 3.16(released last month), and your current version 3.5 was released September 2009 - a literal 7+ years of bug fixing and enhancements.

No other option other than to handle manually.

You shall refer the latest documentation here - [Apache POI Documentation latest](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html)

For Complete list of Deprecated methods - You shall refer here - [Deprecated methods](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/deprecated-list.html#method)

Comment: @kiwiwings.. We need to update JAR files in order to switch to SXSSF.